# 3 sum algorithm - Trying

Tags: java, algorithm, mathematics

Recently I started looking and refreshing about algorithms and decided to try to do the 3 sum algorithm. I did the code below:

```
public static int[] tripletSum(int[] A, int sum) {


    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> data = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        data.put(A[i], true);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    while (i < A.length && j < A.length) {

        Integer a = A[i];

        Integer b = A[j];

        Integer delta = sum - (a + b);

        if (data.containsKey(delta) && a != delta && b != delta && (a + b + delta) == sum) {
            int[] result = {a, b, delta};
            return result;

        }
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'd like opinions about if it is good logic, time complexity, improvements. Any tips and comments will be great.

The piece of code below:

```
if (data.containsKey(remainder) && a != remainder && b != remainder && (a + b + remainder) == sum) {
```

is included to avoid to repeat values in a and b, and to guarantee the sum result as expected.

Thanks

Comment: This 3sum algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM ?

Comment: I hope yes. A long time ago in a technical interview asked me to create an algorithm used to find three values in an array where the sum equals a sum parameter, like [5,1,2,1,8] and the sum expected is 15, interact in the loop finding the values where the sum equals 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment by @konijn and your answer to his comment below your question you tried to implement a variant of the algorithm  [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) but your implementation is **totally wrong**.

Let's start again: given an array and a value k you want to find three elements a, b, c in the array that satisfy the condition a + b + c = k. To obtain a complexity of O(n2) you have to use an hashtable to store values already checked in the array so if you have a and b and the hashtable contains the value c = k - (a + b) the algorithm ends. In this case instead of an hashtable I will use an `hashset` like I explain later.
The initial implementation of your method will be like this:

```
public static int[] tripletSum(int[] arr, int k) {  
    final int n = arr.length;

    if (n < 3) { return null; }

    int[] numbers = Arrays.copyOf(arr, n);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    ...omitted
}
```

You have chosen to return the triplet (a, b, c) if a + b + c = k, otherwise you return the `null` triplet if the length of the array if less than 3 or none triplet (a, b, c) satisfies the sum condition a + b + c = k.
Now add the logic of algorithm to the body of method like below:

```
public static int[] tripletSum(int[] arr, int k) {  
    final int n = arr.length;

    if (n < 3) { return null; }

    int[] numbers = Arrays.copyOf(arr, n);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if (i > 0 && numbers[i] == numbers[i - 1]) { continue; }    
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int a = numbers[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            int b = numbers[j];
            int c = k - (a + b);
            if (set.contains(c)) {
                return new int[] {a, b, c};
            }
            set.add(b);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I made a copy of the original array and sorted it so all duplicate numbers are consecutive : in this way in the loop once for a number a the there are no b and c that satisfy the condition a + b + c = k, the loop ignore all equal numbers to n with instruction `continue`.

I use the `HashSet` to store the c values, so in every cycle of the loop I have a and b and I check if the hashset contains the value c = k - (a + b). If yes, the function returns the triplet (a, b, c) otherwise the value b is stored in the hashset if not already present as a c value for next iterations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `HashMap`, you are not using the bools anywhere. So I think You could just use `HashSet`. Which you don't need to feed in foreach, instead simply pass the integers as constructor parameter.

```
var set = new HashSet(A);
```

You don't have to compare both `i` and `j`

```
i < A.length && j < A.length
```

if `j` is always one larger then `i`, just compare with `j`.

This condition is always true:

```
(a + b + delta) == sum
```

since that is the way it was obtained in the first place:

```
Integer delta = sum - (a + b);
```

This:

```
int[] result = {a, b, delta};
return result;
```

could be just

```
return {a, b, delta};
```

You are returning `null` where you claim to return `int[]`, not sure if that's correct.

Anyway I think your implementation does not work as intended, because it only looks for sums of two consecutive and third anywhere. It fails for example on [5,1,2,1,8] looking for 15=5+2+8.

Comment: Thanks @slepic, but I tried using the [5,1,2,1,8], and got the result 5 2 8. If I get the sum result expected less every 2 elements from the array, the result will be a key found in the Hash.
For example: If the array is [5,1,2,1,8] and looking to find three values inside where is the sum is equal to 15, when interacting in the loop I'll get the first and second element(A[0] and A[1]), 1 + 2 (array sorted) and 15 - 3 = 12. Is it 12 a key? not.
Now we'll interact again, and so on :-)

Comment: @EdsonMartins hehe ok I guess I will have to actually run it :)

Comment: Thanks again @slepic, I changed to HashSet, the loop with j variable, etc Perfectly heheh.

Comment: @EdsonMartins well, first I realized this is not C# as I thought :D But nevertheless with only few little changes it works in C# too :) Anyway it does not find solution for [5,1,2,1,8]=15, but it finds it for [5,1,2,8]=15. And going through the code logicaly leads me to conclusion that this should be the case in java as well, as I already wrote in my answer. I understand how you implemented it and that exactly makes me think it should not find solution [5,1,2,1,8]=15. No idea how it did, unless you changed the code already..

Comment: @EdsonMartins cause 15-(5+1)=9 -> not in the set; 15-(1+2)=12 -> not in the set; 15-(2+1)=12 -> not in the set; 15-(1+8)=6 -> not in the set; the end.

Comment: strange, but it's working in my idea. This is a Java code.
The initial logic, I'm sorting first and then calling the method.
The code is:
int[] arr = {5,1,2,1,8};
  
  Arrays.sort(arr);
  int[] values = tripletSum(arr, 15);

Comment: Another point, I changed the code only to use HashSet.
HashSet<Integer> data = new HashSet<>();
  
  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
   data.add(A[i]);
  }
  
  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;

Comment: I didn't try to use the method addAll because I need to rewrite the logic used to find the delta, instead of using the array like A[index].

Comment: Hmm but then of course it works, because if it is sorted then it is different sequence and I intentionaly picked one that will fail and you changed it :D

Comment: wow. I see :-D. Yes, I sorted first

Comment: maybe now is a good challenge to modify and use logic without sort method :-D

Comment: But then your implementation only works because you sort first. I think you can still find a sequence that will fail even sorted, though it is hard to think of one... Anyway in that case the sort is basicaly part of your algorithm and as such increases time complexity of the implementation. And not by a small amount.

Comment: @EdsonMartins Yeah, definitely look on the wikipedia linked in comments under your question. That looks like something I could have imagined as natural way to solve it...

Comment: I hope if asking the interviewer about how the data will come (sorted or not). If sorted my algorithm will work, right? :-D

Comment: I'll take a look again the wiki. Cheers